# Tricky multiple string searching in txt file using Python

Tags: python

I have a tricky search scenario with regards to scanning through a text file and was hoping for some ideas as to how would be the best method to process the scenario, either through breaking it down or any useful modules out there.  I have a text file in the form of the example below where I am looking for a text sequence like “test1(OK) test2(OK)”.  If this search pattern is met I then need to go back up the file and find the last 4 entries of another string “String Group A“ and capture information “Useful information for A“ from each of these previous string groups.  To make things more difficult I have similar information groups for ‘B’ which makes things tricky, and I have to do the same process for all Group  ‘B’ information!

```
String Group A
    Useful information for A

String Group A
    Useful information for A

String Group B
    Useful information for B

String Group A
    Useful information for A

String Group B
    Useful information for B

String Group A
    Useful information for A

Other Main String for A
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

Other Main String for B
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for B” from “String Group B”

String Group B
    Useful information for B

String Group A
    Useful information for A

And so on…
```

Like I say, I am looking for ideas on the best way forward as the gathering information in this text file seems to jump around too much.  I had an idea of looking and counting ‘String Group A’ as line(x) and then when the “test1(OK) test2(OK)” condition is met to go back to line(x) and line(x-1) and line(x-2) and line(x-3) and grab each “Useful information for A”,  but I am not convinced this is the best way forward.  I should point out that the text file is huge and contains 1000s of entries for String Group A and B.

Thanks for reading,

MikG

Comment: Are you interested in any occurrence of 'Useful information for A' before 'test1(OK) test2(OK)' and 'Other Main String for A' or only those immediately before?

Comment: Hi Praxeolitic, I am looking for only the previous 4 entries of 'String Group A' once 'test1(OK) test2(OK)' for 'A' is found, likewise I would need to repeat for 'B' conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to define a circular vector class that keeps track of only the data that might be needed while processing the file from top to bottom. It has a decent amount of commenting so that it can be understood and isn't just a code dump. The specifics of the parsing is of course strongly dependent on what exactly your inputs look like. My code makes assumptions based on the example file that you will likely need to change. The use of startswith(), for example, might be too rigid, depending on your inputs, and you may want to use find() instead.

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from itertools import chain

class circ_vec(object):
    """A circular fixed vector.
    """
    # The use of slots drastically reduces memory footprint of Python classes -
    # it removes the need for a hash table for every object
    __slots__ = ['end', 'elems', 'capacity']
    # end will keep track of where the next element is to be added
    # elems holds the last X elemenst that were added
    # capacity is how many elements we will hold

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        # we only need to specify the capacity up front
        # elems is empty
        self.end = 0
        self.elems = []
        self.capacity = capacity

    def add(self, e):
        new_index = self.end
        if new_index < len(self.elems):
            self.elems[new_index] = e
        else:
            # If we haven't seen capacity # of elements yet just append
            self.elems.append(e)
        self.end = (self.end + 1) % self.capacity

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.elems)

    # This magic method allows brace [ ] indexing
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self.elems):
            print("MY RAISE")
            raise IndexError
        first = self.capacity - self.end - 1
        index = (index + first) % self.capacity
        # index = (self.end + key ) % self.capacity
        # print("LEN = ", len(self.elems))
        # print("INDEX = ", index)
        return self.elems[index]

    # This magic method allows iteration
    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.elems:
            return iter([])
        elif len(self.elems) < self.capacity:
            first = 0
        else:
            first = self.end
        # Iterate from the oldest element to the newest
        return chain( iter(self.elems[first:]), iter(self.elems[:first]) )

string_group_last_four = { k : circ_vec(4) for k in ['A', 'B'] }
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    string_group_context = None
    # We will manually iterate through the file.  Get an iterator using iter().
    it = iter(f)
    # As per the example, the file we're reading groups lines in twos.
    buf = circ_vec(2)
    try:
        while(True):
            line = next(it)
            buf.add(line.strip())
            # The lines beginning with 'String Group' should be recorded in case we need them later.
            if line.startswith('String Group'):
                # Here is the benefit of manual iteration.  We can call next() more than once per loop iteration.
                # Sometimes once we've read a line, we just want to immediately get the next line.
                # strip() removes whitespace and the newline characters
                buf.add(next(it).strip())
                # How exactly you will parse your lines depends on your needs. Here, I assume that the last word in
                # the current line is an identifier that we are interested in.
                string_group = line.strip().split()[-1]
                # Add the lines in the buffer to the circular vector belonging to the identifier.
                string_group_last_four[string_group].add( list(l for l in buf) )
                buf = circ_vec(2)
            # For lines beginning with 'Other Main String for', we need to
            # remember the identifier but there's no other information to
            # record.
            elif line.startswith('Other Main String for'):
                string_group_context = line.strip().split()[-1]
            # Use find() instead of startswith() because the
            # 'test1(OK) # test2(OK)' lines begin with whitespace. startswith()
            # would depend on the specific whitespace characters which could
            # be confusing.
            elif line.find('test1(OK) test2(OK)') != -1:
                print('String group' + string_group_context + ' has a test hit!')
                # Print out the test lines.
                for l in buf: print(l)
                print('Four most recent "String Group ' + string_group_context + '" lines:')
                # Use the identifier dict to get the last 4 relevant groups of lines
                for cv in string_group_last_four[string_group_context]:
                    for l in cv: print(l)
    # Manual iteration is terminated by an exception in Python.  Catch and swallow it
    except StopIteration: pass
print("Done!")
```

**Test file contents.**
I tried to make it a little weird to exercise the code a bit.

```
Other Main String for A
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

String Group 1 A
    Useful information for A

String Group 2 A
    Useful information for A

Other Main String for A
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

String Group 1 B
    Useful information for B

String Group 3 A
    Useful information for A

String Group 2 B
    Useful information for B

String Group 4 A
    Useful information for A

String Group 5 A
    Useful information for A

String Group 6 A
    Useful information for A

String Group 3 B
    Useful information for B

Other Main String for A
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

Other Main String for B
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

Other Main String for B
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

String Group 4 B
    Useful information for B

Other Main String for B
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”

String Group 7 A
    Useful information for A

Other Main String for A
    test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
```

**Output**

```
String groupA has a test hit!
Other Main String for A
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group A" lines:
String groupA has a test hit!
Other Main String for A
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group A" lines:
String Group 1 A
Useful information for A
String Group 2 A
Useful information for A
String groupA has a test hit!
Other Main String for A
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group A" lines:
String Group 3 A
Useful information for A
String Group 4 A
Useful information for A
String Group 5 A
Useful information for A
String Group 6 A
Useful information for A
String groupB has a test hit!
Other Main String for B
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group B" lines:
String Group 1 B
Useful information for B
String Group 2 B
Useful information for B
String Group 3 B
Useful information for B
String groupB has a test hit!
Other Main String for B
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group B" lines:
String Group 1 B
Useful information for B
String Group 2 B
Useful information for B
String Group 3 B
Useful information for B
String groupB has a test hit!
Other Main String for B
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group B" lines:
String Group 1 B
Useful information for B
String Group 2 B
Useful information for B
String Group 3 B
Useful information for B
String Group 4 B
Useful information for B
String groupA has a test hit!
Other Main String for A
test1(OK) test2(OK)  *** Condition Met *** #Now go back and collect the last 4 entries of “Useful information for A” from “String Group A”
Four most recent "String Group A" lines:
String Group 4 A
Useful information for A
String Group 5 A
Useful information for A
String Group 6 A
Useful information for A
String Group 7 A
Useful information for A
Done!
```

Comment: Hi Praxeolitic, thanks for your very comprehensive relpy.  Unfortunatley I think I am well out of my depth for this type of text processing, I can see your script working for my example script, but when I change the strings around for my original text file I don't get the previous 4 lines printed out, even using line.find() inplace of line.startswith()

Comment: Keep in mind that find() doesn't return a bool. If there's no match it returns -1, otherwise it returns the starting index of the match. The code in my answer has an example of this. The Python documentation on all this is good. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: Perfect - I have accepted your answer! With your advice I managed to capture the text packets I was after, you have been extremely helpful, and I am very grateful and somewhat overawed!  If I wanted to encapsultate certain text (say 4 and 5 lines down from the "String Group A" marker would I just enumerate the captured lines then count up and split the line?

Comment: You'd have to modify "buf = circ_vec(2)", which controls how many lines are being captured.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I interpret it is to find a list of occurances of a specific pattern, and from this list, extract a block of text.  The following find_all() routine extracts all occurances of a pattern (sub) from a string (s).  The following example sketches how to use this to get test results, but it depends on finding a subsequent end_pattern.

```
def find_all(s, sub):
    indxs = []
    start = 0
    ns = len(s)
    nsub = len(sub)
    while True:
        indx = s.find(sub, start, ns)
        if indx < 0: break
        indxs.append(indx)
        start = indx + nsub; print(start)
    return indxs
```

Sketch of use, given string (test_results) and string group A (group_A_pattern) and a pattern to end of "useful information for A" (end_group_pattern):

```
def get_test_results(test_results, group_A_pattern, end_group_pattern):
    starts = find_all(test_results, group_A_pattern)
    useful_A = []
    for start0 in starts[-4:]:
        start = start0 + len(group_A_pattern)
        stop = test_results.find(end_group_pattern, start)
        useful_A.append(test_results[start:stop])
    return useful_A
```

Here is the test code:

```
test_results = 'groupA some-useful end junk groupA more-useful end whatever'
group_A_pattern = 'groupA'
end_group_pattern = 'end'
get_test_results(test_results, group_A_pattern, end_group_pattern)
```

Running the above test code produces:

```
[' some-useful ', ' more-useful ']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xxyzzy.  I decided to go with Praxeolitic's answer in the end, though I think for both of your answers I am a little out of my depth!